# Как передать данные из Form2 в Form1 не закрывая формы?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть `Form1`. На ней размещены `richTextBox1` и `Button1`. `Button1` вызывает `Form2`.

На `Form2` есть `textBox1` и `Button1`.

ВОПРОС:
Как при нажатии на `Form2.Button1` пеердать текстовое сообщение из `Form2.textBox1` в `Form1.richTextBox1`? При этом не закрывая ни одну из форм?

Есть подозрение, что лучший и самый универсальный способ это сделать — это использовать делегаты. Но что-то я никак не соображу, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: напишите евент в аргументах которого будите передавать данные из текстового поля, на первой форме подпишитесь на этот евент, евент должен сработать при нажатии кнопки, ну это если кратко

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аргументы события

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string _text;
    public string Text { get { return _text; } }

    public MyEventArgs(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }
}
```

форма 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args);

    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    protected virtual void MyEventRaise()
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(textBox1.Text));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEventRaise();
    }
}
```

на первой фоме подписываемся на событие

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.MyEvent += Form2_MyEvent;
```

разбираем что у нас там пришло

```
private void Form2_MyEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
    // Текст из текстбокса, вставляем куда нам надо
    richTextBox1.Text += args.Text;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за чайниковский вопрос, но всеже... Все равно где размещать класс MyEventArgs?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Разместите его отдельным файлом, если не знаете куда еще поместить, это будет самое правильное решение, а так, следует почитать про наймспейсы

Comment: при компиляции получаю три ошибки.

CS1520 Method must have a return type
S0103 The name '_text' does not exist in the current context
CS1729 'MyEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: у меня собирается вполне успешно, проверяйте, все ли правильно у вас в коде

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел ошибку! Работает Великолепно! То, что надо!

Comment: Обращайтесь если что :)

Comment: Даже не сомневайтесь! )))

Comment: Есть вопрос. Зачем нам понадобился метод MyEventRaise? Почему нельзя в button1_Clic выполнить все теже действия?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin он у нас объявлен виртуальным, то-есть его можно переопределить например, можно вызвать из друших мест, да и вообще так правильнее с точки зрения архитектуры

Comment: Еще вопрос. С какой целью понадобилось реализовывать класс MyEventArgs? Можно же обойтись и без него, объявив в делегате нужный тип. Только поймите меня правильно, я спрашиваю с целью самообразования, а не с целью критики. Хочу разобраться во всех нюансах и понять что правильно, а что нет.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin аргументы у кастомных евентов должны наследоваться от EventArgs. Если хотите разобраться то почитайте книжку, например вот эту http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21236101/

Comment: В этой книге просто написано _"В соответствии с соглашением, классы, содержащие информацию о событиях, передаваемую обработчику события, должны наследовать от типа System.EventArgs, а имя типа должно заканчиваться словом EventArgs. "_ Но ничего не сказано о том, что это за соглашение и почему так принято. Просто оно и так и так работает, а почему нужно делать так, а не иначе - непонятно.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Представте, что вы работаете на крупную организацию в которой тысячи программистов (но на самом деле хватит и двух) и вдруг все начали писать как им вздумается, как в таком случае поддерживать код в рабочем состоянии? Думаю я ответил на вопрос о соглашениях ;)

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько путей решения это задачи:

1. Передать в Form2 ссылку на Form1 - это можно сделать классическими   тремя путями: конструктор, свойство, контекст;

**Конструктор:**

*форма 1*

```
var form_2 = new Form2(this);
```

*форма 2*

```
private Form1 form_1;
public Form2(Form1 obj)
{
    this.form_1 = obj;
}

private void f()
{
    this.form_1.RichTextBox1.Lines[0] = "Hello";
}
```

**Свойство:**

*форма 1:*

```
var form_2 = new Form2();
form_2.UpForm = this;
```

*форма 2:*

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form1 UpForm { get; set; }

   private void f()
   {
       this.UpForm.RichTextBox1.Lines[0] = "Hello";
   }
}
```

**Контекст:**

Делается через статический объект.

*Объект:*

```
static internal class GLOBAL
{
    static public Form1 CONTEXT_FORM;
}
```

*форма 1:*

```
GLOBAL.CONTEXT_FORM = this;
var form_2 = new Form2();
```

*форма 2:*

```
private void f()
{
    GLOBAL.CONTEXT_FORM.RichTextBox1.Lines[0] = "Hello";
}
```

2. Через событие: описать в Form2 event, а в Form1 на него подписаться. (Вам уже описал Dmitry)

Comment: А нельзя ли привести конкретный пример обоих способов?

Comment: Не совсем понял про передачу в Form2 ссылку на Form1 через конструктор. Чем в Вашем примере явялется переменная form_1 и где ее нужно объявлять?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin, да не пописал :(, сейчас исправлю. В форме 2 должна быть такая переменная или свойство.

Comment: Допустим это будет свойством объявляемым в Form2. Но что я передаю конструктору через ключевое слово this? Если бы я передавал экземпляр класса, то мне были бы доступны его методы, свойства объекы и прочее. А иначе Visual Studio не дает доступ к RichTextBox1. И вот тут я уже не понимаю как быть.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin this - это ссылка на себя

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Только обратил внимание, что вы, добавили плашку winforms. В "формах" ЕМНИП компоненты на форме объявлены как protected, то есть доступа к ним из другой формы не будет, вам понадобится на форме 1 добавлять публичные поля для передачи данных, либо в свойствах конкретных компонентов указывать публичный доступ