# Работа с WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

надо в **WinForms** C# из одной формы где есть `datagridview` с данными,и  надо что при переходе в другую форму один из столбцов, в помеченный строке, у которой уникальная значения автоматически отправлять на вторую форму

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ на более ранний вопрос о передачи данных с формы на форму http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465226/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-form2-%D0%B2-form1-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B/465231#465231

Comment: а как взять значение из определенной ячейки в datagridview?

Comment: примерно так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571963/how-to-get-datagridview-cell-value-in-messagebox

Comment: можно сделать так что бы в клике на батон открывалась новая форма и в текстбоксе который находится  в этом форме было написано значение из  Form1.datagridview ?
с этими примерами как те получается

Comment: Можно, но тогда вам надо использовать другой подход, передать данные например через конструктор или через свойство открываемой формы

Comment: Оформил в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Передача данных в открываемую форму**

Описание формы:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form2(object value)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
   }
}
```

Передача данных с родительской формы:

```
var val = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value; 
var form2 = new Form2(val);
```