# WinForms. Передача данных между формами - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два `Combobox`'а (`orgbox1` и `orgbox2`), каждый в своей форме. Необходимо передать все записи из раннего в поздний.
Прочитал [это](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html), пункт 2.5

Делаю так:

Первая форма (родитель):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add add = new add();
    add.Owner = this;
    add.ShowDialog();
}
```

Вторая форма:

```
public partial class add : Form
{
    public add()
    {
        guest Guest = Owner as guest;
        InitializeComponent();
        DBCoonect();
    }
```

На обоих формах установил модификаторы в `public` для элементов.

Но не могу использовать `orgbox1` (комбобокс первой формы), пытаюсь к нему обратиться как `Guest.orgbox1.DataSource`.

Подскажите — как верно?

P.S. Я неправильно сделал что присвоил Родителя в конструкторе второй формы?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у Вас orgbox приватный?

Comment: Возможный дубликат [вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465226/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-form2-%d0%b2-form1-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b/465229)

Comment: Нет, модификаторы обоих полей выставил public

Comment: вторая форма - это диалог или самостоятельная дочерняя форма?

Answer (score 2):

1. При создании дочерней формы -- ты созавай экземпляр формы не локальным а глобальным. Внутри Мейн формы.
2. С главной формы передавай себя (this) в конструктор дочерней формы(ну и изменить конструктор соответственно что б в него можно было передать нужный Form). Конструктор должен делать то же самое с этой формой -- создать экземпляр глобальным внутри формы.
3. Как следствие ты сможешь обращатся с одно формы на другую с любого места любой формы и делать что хочешь.

Если написал не понятно - задавай вопросы.