# C# Данные из родительского окна в дочернее(ширина)

Tags: c#, winforms

Как передать данные из родительского окна в дочернее(ширина)?

Comment: Как вы пробовали это сделать? Что не получилось?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чём вы видите проблему, какую задачу решаете и т. д. Возможно, вам подойдет один из [этих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465226).